# jQuery on click to target a particular element of a group

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="#link_1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#link_2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#link_3">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div id="link_1" class="item open">
  <h3>Title 1</h3>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="link_2" class="item">
  <h3>Title 2</h3>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="link_3" class="item">
  <h3>Title 3</h3>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

By default some of the 'item' div(s) will be open.
I am adding a click event to '.links a'. 
I need to add an 'open' class for the corresponded item group.

Currently it's adding '.open' to all 'div.item' 
http://jsfiddle.net/rmbor/boc0c6ef/

Any help with explanation are highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite your logic like below,

```
var $href = $('.links a[href^="#"]');

$href.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().siblings('.item').eq($href.index(this)).addClass("open");
});

$(document).on('click', 'h3', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.item')
    .toggleClass('open');
});
```

Find the `index` of corresponding `anchor` tags. By using it access the relevant target elements and add class to it.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/boc0c6ef/2/)

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu, that helped.